# Efficiently adding multiple elements to the start of a List in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list that I would like to add multiple elements to the start of. Adding to the start is linear time because it is backed by an array and has to be moved one at a time, and I cannot afford to do this as many times as I would have to if I implemented this the naive way.

If I know exactly how many elements I am about to add, can I shift them all that much so that the linearity only has to happen once?

```
List<int> myList = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
//Desired list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

//Unacceptable
for (int i = 5; i>=0; i--){
    myList.Insert(0,i);
}

//Is this concept possible?
int newElements = 5;
for (int i = myList.Count; i>=0; i--){
    myList[i+newElements] = myList[i];//This line is illegal, Index was out of range
}
for (int i = 0; i< newElements; i++){
    myList[i] = i+1;
}
```

In this specific instance, access needs to be constant time, hence the usage of `List`. I need to be able to add elements to both the start and end of the data structure as fast as possible. I am okay with O(m) where m is the number of elements being added (since I don't think that can be avoided) but O(m*n) where n is the number of elements in the existing structure is far too slow.

Comment: Consider a `LinkedList<T>`

Comment: You should consider using an other type of Collection, like LinkedList<> for instance

Comment: I think you're getting too stuck up on how your collection works.  If doing inserts to the beginning of the collection needs to be optimized, then maybe a `LinkedList<int>` would be better, but then you have to balance that with the slower lookup performance.

Comment: myList.InsertRange(0, Desiredlist);

Comment: If you have the collection you need to insert already, just use [InsertRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884ee1fz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `myList[i+newElements] = myList[i];` is illegal because you're accessing an index that is greater than `Count`. You can add 5 dummy items first; then it will be legal. You can also use `InsertRange()`

Comment: are the numbers to be added from another array?

Comment: @Plutonix, the list I'm using needs to be indexed, so I can't use a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `InsertRange` which will be linear if the inserted collection implements `ICollection<T>`:

```
var newElements = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
myList.InsertRange(0, newElements);
```

Comment: Clean syntax but not sure it is more efficient.  According to the documentation This method is an O(n + m) operation, where n is the number of elements to be added and m is Count.

Comment: @Frisbee - More efficient than what? This does what the question asks for in that it performs one shift of the list and then performs the `m` inserts.

Comment: @Frisbee - If you just perform `m` inserts at the beginning of a list that will be `O(m * n)` since the entire list must be copied `m` times.

Comment: OK may be my misunderstanding

Comment: @Lee Sounds like this is exactly what I'm looking for. I don't think you can get much better than O(n+m) in an indexed structure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`myList.InsertRange(0, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });`

Answer (score 1):

If your new elements are already in a `List`, you could use `List.AddRange` to add your "old" list to the end of the to-be-added-items-list.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine `myList.InsertRange(0, newElements)` would suit you well. Microsoft will have made that as efficient as it can be.

Comment: Actually, they have made it very inefficient in case `newElements` is an `IEnumerable<T>` that does not implement `ICollection<T>`. It will enumerate and insert one item at a time :)

Comment: Fair enough, but it's as efficient as it can be if you're passing in a plain old enumerable :)

Just trying to beat Microsoft or any big company at efficiency is usually foolish.

The inefficient part of your code is just NOT here :)